# Can't backup my PostgreSQL database [ peer authentication failed for user "USER" ]

Tags: django, postgresql, ubuntu

sql file that I backedup a long time ago of my website database and now I'm trying to use it but everytime I use:

```
psql -U <username> -d --password <dbname> -1 -f <filename>.sql
```

it gives me this error

> peer authentication failed for user "USER"

I tried to edit the pg_hba.conf but that did nothing.

how can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several mistakes:

1. You didn't edit `pg_hba.conf` properly or you forgot to reload PostgreSQL.

   Add your `pg_hba.conf` to the question for more details.
2. Your command line is syntactically incorrect; `--password` will be interpreted as argument of `-d`. Try

   ```
   psql -U <username> -d <dbname> --password -1 -f <filename>.sql
   ```